# Restoration of time-shifted audio file using matlab

Tags: signal-processing, electrical, matlab

The two stereo channels of audio file are time shifted. Which is the easy model to restore the file to the original?

I have a partial solution something like:

- Loading file like, `[data,fs]=audioread('xyz.wav');`
- Calculating the power spectrum of each channel using fft, `fourier1 = fft(data(:,1),1024);`
- Get power spectrum channel 1 and channel, `Powspec_1 = fourier1.*conj(fourier1)/1024;`
- Normalizing the spectrum
- Then compute cross correlation between these pair of signals

I can't understand the next steps to get original file or may be a simple model could help me to solve it.

Regards,

Lalit

Comment: Using the frequency domain makes no sense whatseoever.  If the channels are time shifted relative to one another, introduce a time delay in one to compensate.  Even if you were trying to *identify* the shift you'd probably want to do correlation in the *time domain*.  Besides this does not really seem to be on topic as an EE question; you're asking how to manipulate data in software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with EE. Sounds like a DSP.SE question -- but you need to be clear about what you need. You talk about "restoring" a file, but then the steps seem to be more oriented toward analysis.

Comment: Use a wave processing tool like wavelab or wave editor. Job done.

Comment: sounds like homework